# How can I separate this grouped data by column value in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a table with the follow structure:

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE data = "Map load" 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5

user_id timestamp            data
3       2017-03-29 18:11:25  Map load
2       2017-03-29 18:10:11  Map load
5       2017-03-29 18:02:07  Map load
5       2017-03-29 17:48:03  Map load
3       2017-03-29 17:38:48  Map load
```

I wish to group rows by 15 minute intervals, which I have done. 
However, I also need to segment this data by user_id.

Grouped by interval:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/900)*900) AS `Time`,
COUNT(*) AS `Map Load` FROM logs 
WHERE data = "Map load"
GROUP BY `Time` ORDER BY `Time` DESC LIMIT 3

Time                Map Load
2017-03-29 18:00:00 3
2017-03-29 17:45:00 1
2017-03-29 17:30:00 1
```

Desired Result Layout:

```
Time                user_id=3 user_id=2 user_id=5
2017-03-29 18:00:00 1         1         1
2017-03-29 17:45:00 0         0         1
2017-03-29 17:30:00 1         0         0
```

I have other 60 users, so other than join a copy of this table for each user_id on the 15min interval timestamps, is there another method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 900) * 900) as time,
    sum(user_id = 3) as User_id_3,
    sum(user_id = 2) as User_id_2,
    sum(user_id = 5) as User_id_5
from logs
where data = "Map load"
group by time
order by time desc LIMIT 3
```

If you have more number of users, it's more advisable to not *pivot* values in SQL but rather do it you application code:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 900) * 900) as time,
    user_id,
    count(*) as cnt
from logs l
join (
    select FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 900) * 900) as time
    from logs
    group by time
    order by time desc limit 3
    ) t on FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 900) * 900) = t.time
where data = 'Map load'
group by time,
    user_id
order by time desc;
```

Comment: This works fine, however for 60+ users, is it sensible to have linearly growing query as more users join? Im not sure this would be maintainable unless there is a way i can generate that for every user_id? `SELECT user_id FROM users`

Comment: @Lawrence_1718 - In that case don't pivot the table data in SQL. Do it in your application code. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: thanks for the advice but i dont have much choice now, need this for data that has already been generated, thanks for the help though!